# DC motors not drawing enough current when in parallel, too much when alone

Tags: power, batteries, motor, dc, dc-motor

I'm working on a small RC car and I've run into a problem. I plan to use a set of size 130 motors for movement, however, I'm struggling to power them properly.

My idea is to power 4 of them at once, wired in parallel, off of 4 AA cells wired in series (for a final voltage of just under 6 V). (I'll be using an Arduino and a RZ7886 IC to control them later, but I'm stuck already.)

Note that these motors are from AliExpress and dirt cheap (*dirt* = 2 eur for 10 pcs) and so they're the primary suspect for this issue. Here's an excerpt with relevant information from their specification:

```
Voltage:3-6V
(...)
Rated Voltage:3v
Reference current :0.35-0.4A
Test: 3V rotate speed: 8000 R/M
```

It is my understanding that, if I wire one to anywhere in between 3 to 6 volts, it would draw between 350 and 400 mA and rotate at 8k rpm with no load attached.

However, that's not the case. When connected, one motor draws significantly more current, from 800mA to almost an entire 1 A from the power source, and runs very hot. The most puzzling thing is that, when more of them are wired in parallel, they do not draw proportionately more power. 2 of them in parallel draw around 1.5 A (in total), but they refuse to spin up without a push, and run very slow, even under no load. Three or four in parallel also draw around 1.5 A (!), and refuse to run, even without load and a push. Obviously, if they can't even free-run, they can't power my 200 g car, even when geared to much lower rpm.

Initially I thought I might not be delivering enough power (even though 1.5 A should power almost 4 of them, according to their specs). I tried powering them straight from a USB supply rated for 5 V / 2 A, but they'd still draw ~1.5 A and not run. I also tried running them from 3 18650 cells wired in parallel (so, ~4V and plenty of current), but still, 1.5 A, no spin. I also tried wiring 2 AA cells in series in parallel with another identical pair for a final ~3V, but to no avail. I also tried wiring a large 4700 μF capacitor across the power source, which did slightly improve performance across all of these tests, but at the cost of even more current and still far from what I would consider satisfactory.

Am I doing something wrong, or can it be confidently said that the motors are garbage and I should get better ones?

Comment: You bought dirt cheap items from an online store. Do you have any proof you were even sold the correct item you intended to buy?

Comment: measure the battery voltage when motors are running

Comment: @Justme yes I know, but how could I have proof? They look the same as the picture, they match the dimensions and they spin. They could be defective, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @jstola the lithium cell drops from 4V to about 3.5V, the USB contraption drops from 5.15V to about 4V, the AAs drop from 6V to 4V.

Comment: @toljaga Exactly my point, you can't know when purchasing random stuff from random source. If they do not draw the rated current at the rated voltage, either the ratings on website are wrong, or the components you were provided are wrong. Maybe complain to the seller.

Comment: If you got the lowest paid, crappiest job in your area that's available as a walk-on (flipping burgers, digging ditches, whatever), have you spent enough time on this to earn enough money to _buy reliable product_?

Comment: A picture of your setup may help.  If the source voltage isn't dropping significantly as you add more motors then there has to be some series resistance _outside_ the source that's dropping voltage as you add motors that's somehow limiting the current.  Just a long skinny pair of wires from the source to where you combine the motor wires into a common point could do it.

Comment: Note, too, that if the motor is rated for 3V and you put 6V on it, it will "try" to run twice as fast; in the process it'll draw a lot more current and possibly get hot.  What happens with two good alkaline AA cells and **very short** wires to one motor?

Comment: @TimWescott I think you're right about the wires. I was not expecting the motors to draw this much, so I was using those Dupont breadboard wires, which are long and thin. I don't have any shorter/higher-gauge wires on hand right now and it's late where I live but I tried wiring a couple of the ones I do have in parallel to reduce the resistance and I'm getting significantly better results. I will source some in the coming days and see what happens.